# The link of the new logo is too big

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, top-bar

[image: The focus state is broken. Please fix.]

I'm new to web development (desktop nerd), but this seems easily fixable for me ;)

---

More information:

Firefox version 51.0.1, Windows 10 Edu v1607+

It happens when I click (but not release the click) onto the logo - or the logo including the Stack Overflow + meta text.

Comment: Browser, etc? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Firefox, I'll add more info in a sec

Comment: Yes @yellowantphil

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Firefox. There's no CSS that I can see causing this.

Comment: It's a Firefox quirk, nothing more. That selection thing is known to act weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

> It happens when I click (but not release the click) onto the logo

Then don't do that ;)